# setup netbios client in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, home-networking, samba, wins-server

I have two laptops with ubuntu 13.10 x64 on them. I want both of them to be able to ping and mount one another via hostname or netbios name which is the same in my case. The computers are called `gluk47-notebook` and `gluk47-pc` (this is actually a 14'' laptop). The mystery is: the notebook pings the pc but not vice versa.

Here is what I have:

```
[root@gluk47-pc ~]# egrep '^hosts' /etc/nsswitch.conf 
hosts:          files wins dns mdns4
[root@gluk47-pc ~]# grep wins /etc/samba/smb.conf 
   wins support = yes
;   wins server = w.x.y.z
;   name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
[root@gluk47-pc ~]# service winbind status
winbind start/running, process 1633
[root@gluk47-pc ~]# service smbd status
smbd start/running, process 712
[root@gluk47-pc ~]# smbtree -N
EARTH
        \\GLUK47-PC                     gluk47-pc server (Samba, Ubuntu)
                \\GLUK47-PC\print$              Printer Drivers
                \\GLUK47-PC\IPC$                IPC Service (gluk47-pc server (Samba, Ubuntu))
        \\GLUK47-NOTEBOOK               gluk47-notebook server (Samba, Ubuntu)
                \\GLUK47-NOTEBOOK\Home                  Домашний принтер
                \\GLUK47-NOTEBOOK\print$                Printer Drivers
                \\GLUK47-NOTEBOOK\software       
                \\GLUK47-NOTEBOOK\video          
                \\GLUK47-NOTEBOOK\IPC$                  IPC Service (gluk47-notebook server (Samba, Ubuntu))
[gluk47@gluk47-pc ~]$ ssh gluk47-notebook
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gluk47-notebook: Name or service not known
```

The answer of the address resolver is instant, unlike usual smb delays for every operation.

After that I ssh'ed directly by ip address and got the following from the notebook:

```
[root@gluk47-notebook ~]# egrep '^hosts' /etc/nsswitch.conf 
hosts:          files dns wins [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4_minimal mdns4
[root@gluk47-notebook ~]# grep wins /etc/samba/smb.conf
   wins support = yes
;   wins server = w.x.y.z
;   name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
[root@gluk47-notebook ~]# service winbind status
winbind start/running, process 2381
[root@gluk47-notebook ~]# service smbd status
smbd start/running, process 23817
[root@gluk47-notebook ~]# smbtree -N
EARTH
        \\GLUK47-PC                     gluk47-pc server (Samba, Ubuntu)
                \\GLUK47-PC\print$              Printer Drivers
                \\GLUK47-PC\IPC$                IPC Service (gluk47-pc server (Samba, Ubuntu))
        \\GLUK47-NOTEBOOK               gluk47-notebook server (Samba, Ubuntu)
[root@gluk47-notebook ~]# smbclient -NL GLUK47-NOTEBOOK
Connection to GLUK47-NOTEBOOK failed (Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)
```

This error is persistent and I'm stuck. What do I miss? Google is not my friend for this case so far :(

BTW if I place `gluk47-notebook` is `/etc/hosts` of the PC, everything works (I played a game on the pc via wine directly from a samba share of the notebook while writing this post), but I need dynamic netbios, not this statically hand-crafted hosts file...
The pc cannot also ping other machines in the network by netbios name. Notebook pings them successfully. Other machines can ping both pc and notebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already knew about putting wins option into nsswitch.conf, I simply give you a direct answer here: You should additionally install package "libnss-winbind" so that your machine can resolve the name through WINS/NetBIOS. The package was installed automatically while winbind being installed on Ubuntu 13.04 and below.